# Passing parameters inside db2 SQLs from an unix shell script

Tags: shell-script, db2

I want to delete certain rows from a table based on my input values to a unix shell script. I am making connections and terminating it inside my shell script.

If you notice right now the field is hardcoded in the where clause.

**How can I pass that value as a parameter to the script?**

```
#!/bin/ksh
set -x
export DB2INSTANCE=db2clnt1
db2 ""CONNECT TO DBNAME user USER using passwd""
db2 ""delete from table where field =\'abcdefghijklmn\'""
db2 ""CONNECT RESET""
```

Answer (score 1):

[Referencing this answer from another community](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45685180/does-db2-cli-support-parameters-markers-in-sql-that-needs-to-be-executed-from-a#answer-45685536)...

> The DB2 CLP does not support using parameter markers.
>
> However, when you are running db2 non-interactively (i.e., from the shell), you can substitute shell variables:

That should leave you with something like:

```
#!/bin/ksh
set -x
export DB2INSTANCE=db2clnt1
db2 "CONNECT TO DBNAME user USER using passwd"
db2 "delete from table where field = '${1}'"
db2 "CONNECT RESET"
```

which can be called with the field value on the command line

```
./myksh.sh "delete-this-field"
```

**It is important to remember though that...**

> ...this is just using shell substitution you'll need to handle adding single quotes around your strings...[and] if your strings have single quotes this becomes more complicated.